# System.Net.Mail doesn't send in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I am trying to implement a "forgot password" method into my site.  It works perfectly in debug.  Using the same code and db, but published to our web server it fails when it tries to send the message.

The error that I get is:

```
There was an error sending you an email.
The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
```

The email is valid, so I have no idea why it is failing.

Because it is a live environment I cannot step through the code to see exactly where and why it is failing.  I implemented db logging so I can see how far it gets before it fails and it successfully executes all code up to this point:

```
 var smtp = new SmtpClient
 {
     Host = host,
     Port = port,
     EnableSsl = ssl,
     DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
     UseDefaultCredentials = false,
     Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPw)
 };
 using (var message = new MailMessage()
 {
     Subject = subject,
     Body = body,
     IsBodyHtml = ishtml,
     From = fromAddress
 })

 {
     foreach (MailAddress t in toCol)
     { message.To.Add(t); }
     foreach (MailAddress c in ccCol)
     { message.CC.Add(c); }
     foreach (MailAddress b in bccCol)
     { message.Bcc.Add(b); }
     smtp.Send(message);
 }
```

It never gets to the next db logging so it has to be failing here.  In my test I have exactly one email address for the `to` and none for `bcc` and `cc`.  When stepping through in debug it correctly loads the single email address and doesn't load any for `cc` and `bcc`.  I have no idea what it is considering to be an invalid email address.

**EDIT:**

We use Google Apps as our mail server so both my workstation and the server have to connect.  I am using the following:

- Host: smtp.gmail.com
- Port: 587
- EnableSsl: true
- Credentials: valid username and password that work in debug

**EDIT 2:**
To incorporate some of the suggestions from you.
The `fromAddress` is set earlier using values from the db like this:

```
DataTable ts = DAL.Notification.GetNotificationSettings();
var fromEmail = ts.Rows[0]["fromadr"].ToString().Trim();
var fromName = ts.Rows[0]["fromname"].ToString().Trim();
var host = ts.Rows[0]["server"].ToString().Trim();
var port = Convert.ToInt32(ts.Rows[0]["smtpport"]);
var ssl = Convert.ToBoolean(ts.Rows[0]["is_ssl"]);
var ishtml = Convert.ToBoolean(ts.Rows[0]["is_html"]);
var bodyTemplate = ts.Rows[0]["bodyTemplate"].ToString();
body = bodyTemplate.Replace("{CONTENT}", body).Replace("{emailFooter}","");// Needs to use the Global emailFooter resource string

var fromAddress = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromName);
```

I have even tried hard coding the from address like this:

```
message.From = new MailAddress("websystem@mydomain.com");
```

I still get the error and it still fails when defining the message.

Any other suggestions on how to find and fix the problem?

**ANSWER**

I did not define the default from address in the web.config like this:

```
    <system.net>
     <mailSettings>
       <smtp from="email@yourdomain.com">
         <network host="smtp.yourdomain.com"/>
       </smtp>
     </mailSettings>   </system.net>
```

So it failed at `var message = new MailMessage()` before I could define the correct `from` address.

I either needed to implement `var message = new MailMessage(From,To)` or provide a default `from` address in web.config (which is what I did)

Comment: Are all "to" and "from" email addresses in a valid email address format?

Comment: Is the From address different in prod perchance?

Comment: If it works in debug, but not in the live server environment, it probably has something to do with settings. Are the settings on your server different? Regarding the `Host`, `Port`, and `Credentials` to create the `SmtpClient`?

Comment: I think you have a typo, the using statements closing ')' is in the wrong place

Comment: @taylorjonl: No typo.  He's allocating and initializing his object within using(...).

Comment: @Matthew I use the same email in test and live and it is valid

Comment: @JustinPihony the db stores the `from` address as it is a system address and so that doesn't change from the test and live.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk I thought about that, but don't know what would change.  I updated the question with additional details about our mail server `Google Apps for Business` and what settings we use.

Comment: Write all your parameters to a log file, and see whether any email address isn't correctly formatted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error can be caused by two things:

1. One of the email addresses your using (for `message.To`, `message.CC` or `message.Bcc`) is invalid, i.e. it doesn't follow the required format of `someuser@somedomain.xxx`.
2. The *From* address configured in *Web.Config* is invalid:

   ```
   <system.net>
     <mailSettings>
       <smtp from="invalid@@email">
         <network host="smtp.gmail.com"/>
       </smtp>
     </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
   ```

Comment: 1. I am using the EXACT same to, cc, and bcc in debug and test.  The only email used for those is my email address and it is `********@gmail.com`   

2. I don't set the from address in the web.config in debug or live.  Which is why I set `UseDefaultCredentials = false`

Any other ideas?

Comment: You will need to figure out where the default *From* address is coming from. Most likely your code dies in `new MailMessage()` because it will try to set the invalid default *From* address before you get a change to set it yourself.

Comment: It comes from my code.  I set it like this: `var fromAddress = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromName);` with the `fromEmail` and `fromName` being provided by the db and valid.

Comment: No, not according to the code you have posted. There you are using the default constructor of `MailMessage` which gets the initial *From* address from the Web.config file.

Comment: So setting `message.From` does not negate the need for defining it in web.config?  I will try that.  Why doesn't it fail in debug?

Comment: The default `MailMessage` constructor fails immediately if there's a problem with the default *From* address. You aren't given a change to set a correct address. It's an unfortunate design.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use try/catch statements to further narrow the problem. I'd also temporarily lose the `using` statement for the MailMessage for easier troubleshooting.

Example:

```
var smtp;
try
{
    smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = host,
        Port = port,
        EnableSsl = ssl,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPw)
    };
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error creating SMTP client: " + exc.Message);
}

var message = new MailMessage();
try
{
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = body;
    message.IsBodyHtml = ishtml;
    message.From = fromAddress;
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error creating MailMessage: " + exc.Message);
}


try
{
    foreach (MailAddress t in toCol)
        message.To.Add(t);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error adding TO addresses: " + exc.Message);
}

try
{
    foreach (MailAddress c in ccCol)
        message.CC.Add(c);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error adding CC addresses: " + exc.Message);
}

try
{
    foreach (MailAddress b in bccCol)
        message.Bcc.Add(b);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error adding BCC addresses: " + exc.Message);
}

try
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error sending message: " + exc.Message);
}
```

Alternatively, you could replace the various MessageBox.Show() statements with something that writes to a log file. By breaking this up you should be able to pinpoint the problem with more accuracy.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` isn't a good idea in an ASP.NET application! :)

Comment: @Richard Doh! An excellent point... I therefore strongly recommend the log file approach. :)

Comment: @JYelton I implemented something similar just now where it should log to a system messaging service.  The last successful log is prior to `var message`.  What is interesting is I don't get any errors recorded in the messaging system, but I still get the error that the email is invalid.  It is like the individual `try` statements aren't failing, but the entire method is (it is wrapped in a try).

Comment: I'm just proposing breaking it down into smaller chunks so that you can get an idea of *where* the error "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address." is being triggered from. Having different log/console messages from multiple try/catch will hopefully assist with that.

Comment: I'm going to agree with others, based on the last successful log being prior to `var message` that `message.From = fromAddress;` is the problem line. Try validating `fromAddress` before using it.

Comment: @JYelton I use the same `from` in debug, so why would it fail in the live?  I define it earlier like this: `var fromAddress = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromName);` with `fromEmail`= `webemail@mydomain.com` and `fromName` = `System Message`  I would like to validate it, but it looks correct, so how else can I validate?

Comment: @JYelton I hoped you were right.  I just tried hard coding the fromAddress to a known valid email and it still fails and still will not log anything after `var message`