# System.Net.Mail Doesn't Work on Production Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, smtpclient

I know this question has been asked several times but my situation is quite different. 
I have a Web API project that has an action method used to send emails to users to confirm their registration. The code is working good on my local machine and on all other local machines. After the first deployment, send email functionality was working fine until at someday, it suddenly stopped working. **There are no exceptions** in the code after attaching the Web API code to the production server IIS, **no exceptions have been found in the log files** and everything seems good. I double checked that the SMTP feature is enabled on the production server.

Further troubleshooting:

1. I've turned off the firewall (no success).
2. In an attempt to isolate the problem, I made a simple C# console application that sends a dummy mail using the same configurations but with no success as well (it works pretty fine locally but with no success on the production server).
3. I have tried the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591149/system-net-mail-doesnt-send-in-production) but with no success as well.

Here is the sample code I'm using:

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromMail);

            // The important part -- configuring the SMTP client
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Port = 587;   // [1] You can try with 465 also, I always used 587 and got success
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; // [2] Added this
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // [3] Changed this
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromMail, fromPassword);  // [4] Added this. Note, first parameter is NOT string.
            smtp.Host = SMTPServer;


            //recipient address
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toMail));

            //Formatted mail body
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;


            mail.Body = body;
            mail.Subject = subject;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            return true;
```

I'm using smtp.office365.com as the SMTP server client.

I have a final question:

> Does System.Net.Mail limits the number of mails sent per
>   day/month/year? or is there any chance that the server has been
>   blocked from sending emails?

Comment: are you getting an exception? what is the response?

Comment: @Darkonekt as stated above, there are no exceptions found from debugging nor in the log files

Comment: Office 365 is a bit tricky to use as an SMTP relay in my experience. I'd guess that your issue is with Office 365, not with System.Net.Mail.The first thing that occurs to me is that the "From" address has to be a valid address/alias on an Office 365 licensed mailbox. More details can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3.

Comment: There could also be the possibility that a firewall is blocking the traffic from the production server.  And that this policy might not be affecting your development environment.  I would make sure that the actual traffic is leaving the network when in production.

Comment: What does this mean? "I double checked that the SMTP feature is enabled on the production server."  I thought you were using office as your SMTP server

Comment: smtp.office365.com has rules associated with it, and also with the account that you login as. You'll also find that if you login too often, logins will start failing for 10 minutes. Try sending email to the same user you are logged in as, they you can make sure your communication code is working, then you'll just have to map out and correct the outlook part :)

Comment: @jefftrotman step 1 in the article you provided is what exactly I'm doing. The problem is quite different I guess. It is working on my local machine but it doesn't on the production server

Comment: @Darkonekt the firewall is turned off on the production server as stated above. I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @Darkonekt regarding your question "What does this mean? "I double checked that the SMTP feature is enabled on the production server." " I thought this option may solve the problem but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this ? I am facing the exact same problem